# Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js' from 'puppeteer.js'

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, react-testing-library

So I am trying to use the latest version of puppeteer (21.3.8) to use for PDF generation from HTML/CSS in my React program. The issue I've been facing is how certain elements within the HTML/CSS misbehave with tables when in "pritning mode" (WIN+P / CMD+P), e.g. page break at incorrect places.

By using the latest version `puppeteer@21.3.8`, I receive the following when trying to run tests that work with versions that are no longer supported (<19.4.0):

`Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js' from 'puppeteer.js'`

I am using jest version: `jest: ^24.9.0` and React-testing-library!

I don't really want to rollback the version of puppeteer since it will break my PDF generation. If anyone know of any fix or suggestions, please let me know. Thanks! :)

What I've tried:

- Reverting version of puppeteer to 18.1.0, making the tests work but the functionality not work
- Installing version in-between 18.1.0 and 21.3.8, making either functionality work and tests not working and vice versa.
- Tried packages such as `puppeteer-extra` and played around with executablePath(), but without success.

Comment: downkoad puppeteer-core as well as puppeteer. [Since 1.7 they're separate libs](https://pptr.dev/)

Comment: [puppeteer-core is a dependency of Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer?activeTab=dependencies), so if you install Puppeteer you get puppeteer-core too. Can you provide a complete, runnable [mcve] of the failing tests, with package.json? I feel like there's a probable version mismatch here.

Comment: @ggorlen yes but depending on package manager it can be anywhere

Comment: @ggorlen It could be a challenge for me to provide a runnable minimal example for the tests I'm afraid, since this issue is in a larger code base which can have a lot of small dependencies that I could easily miss (and might break some rules within the org hehe). I do have the latest version of both puppeteer and puppeteer-core which is 21.3.8, see here:
    "puppeteer": "^21.3.8",
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.3.8",

The issue occurs when trying to use puppeteer via `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');` solves the error, but other tests fail. Would adding a executablePath help maybe

Comment: The tests that fail regards to actually generating the PDF and I receive an async timeout

`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error`

Comment: Hmm. That's a different error than the one you posted in the question, so I'm afraid there's not much I can offer without more details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I suppose that there is a path issue as you described. I will disable my tests for now and work it out later. If I find a solution, I will post i here. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It could be https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#cannot-find-module-puppeteer-coreinternal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this from what I found was to update jest to the latest version. As of writing this, it is

```
npm i jest@29.7.0
```

Not sure exactly how it solves it but according to my research, jest version >=29 seems to know how to handle the split between puppeteer and puppeteer-core that was made version 18.2.0